# C++, arglist-intro indent based on the indentation of previous line?

Tags: c++, cc-mode

Consider the following C/C++ code

```
{
    auto x = f(g(h(
                     "aaa")));
}
```

The `"aaa"` is indented this way, because `c-offset-alist` has `(arglist-intro . +)` (I think that’s the default), which makes it indent one “unit” (4 spaces per my setting) more based on the location of `h`.

I want the `"aaa"` to indent based on the beginning of the previous line, like this:

```
{
    auto x = f(g(h(
        "aaa")));
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting `c-offset-alist` documentation:

> As described below, each cons cell in this list has the form:
>
> ```
> (SYNTACTIC-SYMBOL . OFFSET)
> ```
>
> […]
>
> OFFSET can specify an offset in several different ways:
>
> […]
>
> - If OFFSET is a function or a lambda expression then it’s called with a single
>   argument containing the cons of the syntactic symbol and the anchor position (or
>   nil if there is none). The return value from the function is then reinterpreted
>   as an offset specification.

So you can write a function that would return `+` for the first call and `0` for subsequent calls and assign it to `arglist-intro`, `arglist-cont` and `arglist-intro`. They all constitute being part of the parameters in the function, so when within a single line you get 3 of these, you want to ignore all calls but the first one.

I've hacked up some code that seems to do the job. Since indenting may call the function multiple times for a single line, we save the last line number so we can check if it's still the same one and return `0` for subsequent calls. In addition, to make sure a user may successfully call the function subsequently, we add a hook to `post-command-hook` that resets the line-number. So every time the user re-indents it will return `+` for the first call and `0` for subsequent ones.

```lisp
(defvar c-arglist-indent-last-line 0)

(defun calc-c-arglist-indent(_)
  "Returns + for the first call and 0 for subsequent ones. Thus similar
nested \"structures\" will be indented as if there's only one"
  ;; compare the line to check whether we were called here
  (let ((line-num (line-number-at-pos)))
    (if (= line-num c-arglist-indent-last-line)
        0
      (setq c-arglist-indent-last-line line-num)
      '+)))
(c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty 'calc-c-arglist-indent)
(c-set-offset 'arglist-cont          'calc-c-arglist-indent)
(c-set-offset 'arglist-intro         'calc-c-arglist-indent)

(defun flush-c-argslist-indent-state()
  "Reset `c-arglist-indent-last-line' so the next time user calls
indentation the line will be unset"
  (setq c-arglist-indent-last-line 0))
(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'flush-c-argslist-indent-state())
```

With this code the following C++ gets indented for me just as you want:

```
{
    auto x = f(foo,
        "aaa");

    auto x = f(g(foo,
        "aaa"));

    auto x = f(g(h(
        "aaa")));
}
```